# Magento set as position still display by price

Tags: magento, position, displaytag

I am a rookie, and I\’m taking over another developer\’s website.

Now my problem is that I have already set Best Value in the Adm, and the Toolbar shows Position as default, But products are still displayed by price. 
The position option works only when I click it.

so I think that the previous developer has changed something, but I don\’t know where.

Please somebody give me some advice where to check.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you flushed your cache after making the configuration changes?

Comment: yes of course, thousands of times!

Comment: 1. Make sure the position isn't manually set on the Category level.  2. Try switching to the default Magento theme and seeing if it's template related.

Comment: I changed theme, It's not template related. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have any 3rd party extensions installed?

Comment: I think yes. Is there anything to do with XML file?

Comment: Yes it is in the 3rd party extensions!!! Thank you so much, Even though I need to find which one.

Comment: I find it, it is in the Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List.php      $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection()->setOrder('price', 'asc');   Finally, Thank you Axel.

Answer (score 0):

You can check magento\app\design\frontend\default\YOURTHEME\template\catalog\product\list\toolbar.phtml
for magento 1.7just around line 81

Comment: Hi, he didn't change the toolbar.phtml.